# Split my plots into data/format parts

Tags: pgfplots

In `pgfplots` is there a way to have all the data in a **single** **database** file? Right now I combine the lines that share the same x-values in a single file, but I have to have a different data file for each plot that uses different x-values.
Is there a way to combine these files?

In other words, in the MWE below, is there a way to combine `line12.dat` with `line3.dat`. My plot is much more complicated than this and having a file for each line is quite unwieldy.

I know that I can use `nan` for lines that are not defined in an x-value. But I am hoping there is a better way since, if the lines do not share many x-values (as below), the datafile can become quite verbose.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{line12.dat}
  x y1 y2
  0 1  2
  1 2  5
  2 3  5
  4 5  3
  7 9  1
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{line3.dat}
  x y
  2 1
  4.1 2
  6.1 3
  8.1 5
  10.1 9
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}
    \addplot[] table[x=x, y=y1] {line12.dat};
    \addplot[] table[x=x, y=y2] {line12.dat};
    \addplot[] table[x=x, y=y] {line3.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `nan`. The data file does not have to be friendly to the human eye :).

Comment: One issue with that is that every time I need to add a line, I need to add a `nan` at the end of all the rows making adding a line quite cumbersome. Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general answer is: *No*.
The requirement is that *all* columns have to have the same number of lines.

But it *is* possible for your specific example, because there you have 5 data points in each column ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
    \begin{filecontents*}{line123.dat}
        x1  y1  y2      x3      y3
        0   1   2       2       1
        1   2   5       4.1     2
        2   3   5       6.1     3
        4   5   3       8.1     5
        7   9   1       10.1    9
    \end{filecontents*}
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [x=x1, y=y1] {line123.dat};
        \addplot table [x=x1, y=y2] {line123.dat};
        \addplot table [x=x3, y=y3] {line123.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]